# How can I build nice tables of average partial effects of different generalized linear models with R?

Tags: r, stargazer, coefficients, xtable, standard-error

I am estimating logit models with more than a few variables, and would like to neatly show average partial effects (APEs) for the model in this way:

[image: Example APEs Table]

Basically, show a table like the one that the `stargazer` command would produce for any kind of `lm` or `glm` object, but with APEs instead of slope coefficients and their standard errors rather than the ones for the slope coefficients.

My code goes something like this:

```
# Estimate the models 

fit1<-glm(ctol ~ y16 + polscore + age,
          data = df46,
          family = quasibinomial(link = 'logit'))

fit2<-glm(ctol ~ y16*polscore + age,
          data = df46,
          family = quasibinomial(link = 'probit'))

fit3<-glm(ctol ~ y16 + polscore + age + ed,
          data = df46,
          family = quasibinomial(link = 'logit'))

# Calculate marginal effects

me_fit1<-margins_summary(fit1)
me_fit2<-margins_summary(fit2)
me_fit3<-margins_summary(fit3)
```

The output of a `margins_summary` object, while itself a `data.frame` object, cannot just be passed to `stargazer` to produce the nice looking output it would do with a `glm` object, like `fit1` in my code before.

```
> me_fit1

   factor     AME     SE       z      p   lower   upper
      age -0.0031 0.0005 -5.8426 0.0000 -0.0041 -0.0020
 polscore  0.0033 0.0031  1.0646 0.2871 -0.0028  0.0093
      y16  0.1184 0.0166  7.1271 0.0000  0.0859  0.1510
```

Trying to pass `me_fit1` to `stargazer` simply prints the `data.frame` summary stats, as stargazer would normally do with objects of this type.

```
> stargazer(me_fit1, type = 'text')

=========================================================
Statistic N Mean  St. Dev.  Min   Pctl(25) Pctl(75)  Max 
---------------------------------------------------------
AME       3 0.040  0.068   -0.003  0.0001   0.061   0.118
SE        3 0.007  0.009   0.001   0.002    0.010   0.017
z         3 0.783  6.489   -5.843  -2.389   4.096   7.127
p         3 0.096  0.166     0       0       0.1      0  
lower     3 0.026  0.052   -0.004  -0.003   0.042   0.086
upper     3 0.053  0.085   -0.002  0.004    0.080   0.151
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried using the `coef` and `se` options from `stargazer` to change the coefficients presented of `stargazer(fit1)` to APEs and their errors. While its simple to show APEs, trying to show their standard errors is problematic because it cannot find the names of the variables in order to match them with their coefficients (in this case, their APEs).

Please help! I haven't been able to present decent results because of this problem. You can see an MWE [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvgWfAgB6CDJjMA_uvrUNMJ1Hz9BPQ?e=7QM7mO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a combination of the `modelsummary` and `marginaleffects` packages. (Massive Disclaimer: I maintain both packages.)

[You can install `modelsummary` from CRAN:](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/)

```r
install.packages("modelsummary")
```

[You can install `marginaleffects` from Github](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/) (warning: this package is young and still in development):

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects")
```

Load libraries and fit two models. Store those two models in a list:

```r
library(marginaleffects)
library(modelsummary)

mod <- list(
    glm(am ~ mpg, data = mtcars, family = binomial),
    glm(am ~ mpg + factor(cyl), data = mtcars, family = binomial))
```

Now, we want to apply the `marginaleffects` function to both models, so we use `lapply` to apply it to each element of the list:

```r
mfx <- lapply(mod, marginaleffects)
```

Finally we call `modelsummary` with the `output` argument set to `"markdown"` because Markdown tables look good on Stack Overflow:

```r
modelsummary(mfx, output = "markdown")
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mpg | 0.046 | 0.056 |
|  | (0.017) | (0.035) |
| factor(cyl)6 |  | 0.097 |
|  |  | (0.174) |
| factor(cyl)8 |  | 0.093 |
|  |  | (0.237) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 |
| AIC | 33.7 | 37.4 |
| BIC | 36.6 | 43.3 |
| Log.Lik. | -14.838 | -14.702 |

Comment: This is amazing and totally answers my question. I have two extra queries maybe you can help with: (1) How would you add lines, in order to show percentage correctly predicted (estimated through other packages and kept in a vector) and (2) My actual models require I presented survey-weighted regressions. I understand `marginaleffects` doesn't support that. Would it work with using the output from `margins_summary`?

Comment: Look at the `add_rows` argument of `modelsummary`. Yes, it should work with `margins`.

Comment: Thanks again! Is there any way to put stars next to APEs to signal their significance?

Comment: Have you tried the `stars` argument?

Comment: I will, sorry, kind of new to your package. Cheers

Comment: The documentation is actually pretty detailed. It's usually better to read it before asking on SO.

Comment: Hey there @Vincent, sorry for bothering again. I've used your package extensively for my research paper and find it very useful. I only have one question/suggestion: how would you spread a long table across two pages (I'm using knitr) , kind of like the `longtable` package ?

Comment: No worries. The answer for `modelsummary` is the same that I gave here for `datasummary`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69867682/342331